# Run a bash script, which starts a screen from a specific user in php

Tags: php, linux

I have dug through everything I can find on the topic of starting a screen from PHP.  I'm starting a game server, so I must run it from a specific user so that the server executable looks in the right folder for its other files.  I have changed Apache's user from its default to the user I must run the server from.  When I have `exec('cd /User/FolderWithScript && bash script.sh);`  to emulate what I would do to start it, it doesn't report any errors in /var/log/apache2/error.log, but also doesn't start the server or its screen.

The same thing happens if I were to use `exec('cd /User/FolderWithExecutable && screen -dmS ServerExcutable +Args');` which is essentially what the script does.

If I use `exec(cd /User/FolderWithScript && bash ServerExcutable +Args);` it spits out all of the usual stuff for the server in /var/log/apache2/error.log, but unfortunately also appears to be looking in the wrong directory for most of the game files, which are located in /User/.game.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you get if you run the command with PHP from the command line?

Comment: How do I go about using php in the terminal?

Comment: Look up the sudo command to run a command as a different user.

Comment: Hmm tried this too at first.  Using sudo -u User <command>  and setting permissions for web user as ALL:(User) NOPASSWD: /User/FolderWithScript/script.sh

Comment: Type `php -a` into the command line as the user you want to run php as and type away. ctrl+c to kill it.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add in my sudoers file `www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /Path/To/Script` and then in PHP run `exec('cd /Path/To/Script(AndExecutable) && sudo -u User /Path/To/Script);`  Basically, It wouldn't run correctly unless I ran the script from the folder the executable was in, and it wouldn't run unless I used the entire path to the script as entered in my sudoers file.